# How to refer to user defined literal operator inside a namespace?

Tags: c++, c++11, user-defined-literals

Consider the following:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace X
{
    void operator ""_test(unsigned long long x)
    {
        std::cout << x;
    }
}

int main()
{
    using namespace X;
    10_test;
    // 10_X::test; /* doesn't work */
}
```

I can refer to the [user defined literal operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal#Literal_operators) inside the `namespace X` by an explicit `using namespace X;`. Is there any way of referring to the literal operator without explicitly including the namespace? I tried the

```
10_X::test;
```

but of course doesn't work as the parser believes `X` refers to the name of the operator.

```
X::operator ""_test(10)
```

works but it's clumsy.

Comment: What's the point of a UDL if you have to explicitly qualify it?

Comment: If anything, I would expect it to be `10 X::_test`, since the underscore is part of the literal's name.

Comment: Are you looking for `using X::""_test;` maybe?

Comment: As a work around the literals could be put into their own literal namespace and then you could just include that instead of the entire namespace.  You also have `using X::operator ""_test`

Comment: @NathanOliver `using X::""_test` doesn't do it. I think `using X::operator ""_test` will do.

Comment: @Bathsheba they are two orthogonal things and udl's were "done" and useful while modules are still in a chaotic state of flux and not really that useful (in current form). Why *not* include the useful feature now while letting the not-so-useful one bake a little longer?

Comment: @vsoftco Yep.  Comment edited

Comment: @JesperJuhl: Apologies, I've removed my comment as it had a typo in it. For me though, it's still about priorities. Why were folk even *thinking* about UDLs?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

namespace X {
  inline namespace literals {
    void operator ""_test(unsigned long long x) {
      std::cout << x;
    }
  }
}

int main() {
  {
    using namespace X::literals;
    10_test;
  }
  {
    using X::operator""_test;
    10_test;
  }
}
```

`_test` is both in `X` and `X::literals`.  This permits people to `using namespace X::literals;` without pulling in everything from `X`, yet within `X` `_test` is also available.

Importing an individual literal is a bit annoying.

`std` does this with both `std::chrono` and `std::literals` and `std::chrono::literals`.  `inline namespace`s let you define subsections of your namespace that you think people would want to import as a block without getting the rest of it.

Comment: Great, looks like the way to go.