# date library without using namespace

Tags: c++, date, namespaces

This example uses the [date](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) library without any `using namespace`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <date/date.h>
//using namespace std;
//using namespace date;
int main() {
    date::year_month_day startDate  = 2018_y / 1 / 6;
    std::cout << startDate << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

but does not compile,
error: unable to find numeric literal operator 'operator""_y'

How to use this library without `using namespace`?

UPDATE:

I changed the code as follows, but there are still many errors.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <date/date.h>
int main() {
    date::sys_time<std::chrono::nanoseconds> tp;
    std::istringstream in1{"2018-12-21 01:15:31"};
    in1 >> date::parse("%F %T", td);
    std::cout << tp << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream' {aka 'std::basic_ostream'} and 'date::sys_time ...

Comment: From the page you linked: *"The entire library is in namespace date. The examples in this overview assume:

using namespace date;
using namespace std::chrono;
in order to cut down on the verbosity."*

Comment: If you check [where `_y` is defined in the header file](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/blob/master/include/date/date.h#L939) you will see that it's defined in sub-namespace `literals`. Which means you could do `using namespace date::literals;` to get only the literals while not getting the rest of the `date` namespace.

Comment: Please check the question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <date/date.h>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date::literals;
    date::year_month_day startDate  = 2018_y / 1 / 6;
    std::cout << startDate << '\n';
}
```

And:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <date/date.h>

int
main()
{
    date::sys_time<std::chrono::nanoseconds> tp;
    std::istringstream in1{"2018-12-21 01:15:31"};
    in1 >> date::parse("%F %T", tp);
    using date::operator<<;
    std::cout << tp << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Numeric literal operator 'operator""_y' is declared inside of namespace 'date'.

You can use 'using namespace date' or 'using namespace date::literals'

More information: [How to refer to user defined literal operator inside a namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49054477/how-to-refer-to-user-defined-literal-operator-inside-a-namespace)

Comment: Or you can add operators one by one : "using  date::literals::operator""_y;"